# UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths witout using new cell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, avplayer

I've got cells with AVPlayer playing inside. Sometimes, I want to reload rows while video is playing. I do it using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method:

```
 [_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Since that might be tough to copy `AVPlayerLayer` and `AVPlayer` states into new cell (video restarts after moving from view to another), I would like to update views with new data on cell which was used before:

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cellController = [_cellControllers controllerForIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell = [tableView deque .... ]

    if (!cellController.isPlayingVideo)
    { 
       // use new cell only if video is not playing
       cellController.cell = cell ;
    }       
    [cellController updateViews];

    return cellController.cell;
}
```

Sadly, it's not working, and rows have wrong heights. It seems that for about 200ms height is correctly set, but then it's made shorter by `tableView`. Generally, that seems to cause mess in `UITableView` cells queue. Any idea how can I use the same cell after `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method?

Comment: Why aren't you only reloading the cells which are not playing, and call [cellController updateViews] for the others?

Comment: Because I have to change row's height as well.